# Probability of getting a defined value by freely assembling the top 3 results of a D4+D6+D8+D10 roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I'm trying to compute the probability of getting a given value with the following rules :

- Roll one 4 sided dice + one 6 sided dice + one 8 sided dice + one 10 sided dice.
- Pick the 3 largest results.
- Choose a value by selecting one dice, assembling 2 dice or even summing all 3 dice.

> Example:
>
> - I roll 2 on the 4 sided dice
> - I roll 1 on the 6 sided dice
> - I roll 6 on the 8 sided dice
> - I roll 5 on the 10 sided dice
> - I pick the 3 largest results : 2,6,5
> - Then, I can choose any of the following values: 2, 6, 5, 2+6=8, 2+5=7, 6+5=11, 2+6+5=13

What is the probability of getting a 2 or a 15 or even a 24 with this rules?

In fact, I am searching for a way to generalize this problem so that I can change the number of dice or the number of sides of each dice or even the number of top dice to keep. I created a computer program to obtain this probabilities using brute force, but I would like a more elegant and faster solution.

Comment: yes, I forgot the 2+6+5=13 in the example... thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: For 2 and 28 this can be solved, but for numbers like 15...pfff. And then even generalize it. I have not much hope. Good luck, though. For 28 the probability is $0$ because you cannot reach higher than 10+8+6<28.

Comment: Is "best result" by definition "highest result" here?

Comment: @drhab: Well in fact you forgot the 4 sided dice ;) 4+6+8+10=28

Comment: @drhab: Yes, the "player" have to pick the three highest results.

Comment: But 4+6+8+10 is not a possibility because it requires 4 dice, and you can only pick 3 dice.

Comment: @drhab: humm you are right indeed ... I change it to 24 (and obviously there is only one chance to get 24)

Comment: might try combinatoric arguments the minimum 3 dice can get is 3 the maximum 24( range = 22) there are 1920 possible rolls of all four dice  that means at least 1 of values in the range has 88 rolls that can get it via the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Depending on what kind of "brute force" your computer program uses, there might be a more efficient method. As indicated above, it seems unlikely you will get a neat formula that does not require tedious calculations of many, many cases.

Comment: there are ${4!\over1!}=24$ ways to pick three you are choosing only 1 of them.

Comment: @Valkea What do you mean by faster solution? I've written a very simply Python program to calculate these via "brute force" that runs in about 0.088 seconds on my very old laptop.  How fast do you need?

Comment: @MatthewConroy : when I read your comment I realized that something had to be wrong in my code because my most expensive test (6D6) was computing for about 30 seconds... So I restarted from scratch and now the D4,D6,D8,D10 is returned in 0.043s and the 6D6 in 1.3s. Thank you for that ;)

Comment: @MatthewConroy : unfortunately, I still search for a faster solution because my little program is supposed to handle classical RPG dice rolls (most of them use few dices, but some of them may use up to 15 or 20 dice in a roll). With the new program, a 6d10 roll still takes 30 seconds, a 6d20 roll takes several minutes. That's why I was hoping to find an elegant solution to avoid the brute force approach.

Answer (score 1):

too long for a comment apparently:

just by examining sums of dice you can come up with a lot of restrictions:

1. any total die sum over 18 must include the 10 sided die (4+6+8=18)
2. any total die sum over 20 must include the 8 sided die (4+6+10=20)
3. any total die sum over 22 must include the 6 sided die (4+8+10=22)
4. any three die sum over 10 must contain either the 8 or 10 sided dice(4+6=10)
5. any three die sum over 12 must contain either the 6 or 10 sided dice(4+8=12)
6. any three die sum over 14 must contain either the 6 or 8 sided dice(4+10=14)
7. any three die sum over 16 must contain either the 4 of 8 sided dice(6+10=16)
8. any three die sum over 18 must contain either the 4 or 6 sided dice(8+10=18)
9. any three die sum over 22 must contain the 6 sided die(5 or 6 only, 4+8+10=22)

anyways I'll let you do the actual math.

Comment: Typos in 2 & 3? (+1)

Comment: no Bruce  because 4+6+10= 20 for any total die sum greater than that must include the 8 side die. For 3) since 4+8+10=22 any total die sum over 22 must include the 6 sided die.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** I don't immediately see a method that isn't tedious. 
If I were using enumerative methods such as those suggested so far,
I would almost surely leave out some cases on my first try.

As a check on
your work, it is easy to see that the mean of the sum of three
should be 12.

Also, in a simulation of a million runs, I got the following answers
to four places; at least two or three places should be accurate.

```
s3
     3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13 
0.0038 0.0109 0.0219 0.0365 0.0520 0.0674 0.0805 0.0916 0.0974 0.0987 0.0941 
    14     15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22     23     24 
0.0852 0.0738 0.0594 0.0458 0.0325 0.0216 0.0134 0.0075 0.0039 0.0016 0.0005
```

[image]

I hope someone will suggest a clever combinatorial method.

Comment: via pigeonhole we know that at least one three dice sum ( probably higher once you deal with edge cases) will have to happen 88 times out of 1920 possible rolls. and 1920/4 =480 meaning at least one  group of three non ordered sets of dice appears as the top in theory at least 480 times.